# Chinese RMB symbol converted to dollar sign instead

Tags: xetex, unicode, input-encodings, font-encodings

MWE：

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ctex}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\begin{document}

￥
\end{document}
```

output:

[image]

It only works with `XeLaTeX`. Doesn't even compile using Latex. Error message:package inputenc error...

I would like a workaround so I can type the Chinese Yuan symbol, but more imporantly I would like someone to use this as an oportunity to explain to me what went wrong. I assuming when I paste the ￥ symbol from the web, I really pasted the UTF8 encoding of ￥, and doesn't Xelatex use UTF-8 coding by default? So is it a prblem with font encoding? I tried to read material online but quite frankly I haven't found one that explains to me in way I understand.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be an issue with the default `fandol` font set.  You have several options.  First, you can load a different font set.  This template loads free fonts available on CTAN, and works on either LuaLaTeX or PDFLaTeX:

```
\tracinglostchars=2
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[fontset=none]{ctex}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\defaultfontfeatures{ Scale = MatchLowercase, Ligatures = TeX }
\setmainfont{Noto Serif}[Scale = 1.0]
\setCJKmainfont{Noto Serif CJK SC}[
  Script=CJK,
  Language=Chinese Simplified]
\setsansfont{Noto Sans}
\setCJKsansfont{Noto Sans CJK SC}[
  Script=CJK,
  Language=Chinese Simplified]
\setmonofont{Noto Sans Mono}
\setCJKmonofont{Noto Sans Mono CJK SC}[
  Script=CJK,
  Language=Chinese Simplified]

\begin{document}
￥
\end{document}
```

Alternatively, give `ctex` (or `ctexart`, etc.) a different `fontset` option that’s available on your system, e.g. `windows`, `macnew` or `ubuntu`.  See §4.3 of the `ctex` manual.

Finally, the LaTeX kernel provides `\textyen`, so you could set the `￥` character back to using that:

```
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\newunicodechar{￥}{\textyen}
```

This should work on any engine, if you can get your documents to compile on it.